# What does this map represent? Matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Represent the derivative map on $Pn$ with respect to $B$, $B$ where $B$ is the natural basis $(⟨1,x,...,x^n⟩)$ how that the product of this matrix with itself is defined; what map does it represent?

The action of $d/dx$ on $B$ is $1 → 0$, $x → 1$, $x^2 → 2x$, ...and so this is its
$(n + 1)×(n + 1)$ matrix representation.

My question is how do they they get it is a $(n + 1)×(n + 1)$ matrix representation, what does that mean? More specifically what does $n+1$ mean?

Comment: $n+1$ is the dimension of $P_n$; don't forget that you're counting all the terms from $x_0$ to $x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Take any $p \in P_n$; say, $p = a_0 + a_1x + \ldots + a_nx^n = \left\langle a_0, a_1, \ldots a_n \right\rangle $. Then $\frac{d}{dx}$ maps $\left\langle a_0, a_1, \ldots a_n \right\rangle$ to $\left\langle a_1, 2a_2, 3a_3 \ldots na_n, 0 \right\rangle$.

Now rewrite each of your basis polynomials in vector form. (Of course, when I say "each", the suggestion is that we know that $\dim P_n$ is some specific number, not just $n + 1$. Pick $n$ small enough to be manageable but large enough to be informative:  Say, $n = 4$.) See what vectors $\frac{d}{dx}$ maps them to. Do you know how to set up the matrix from there? (That's where you'll see $(n + 1) \times (n + 1)$ come in.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, $n+1$ is the dimension of $P_n$, as its basis, $B$ has $n+1$ elements: $1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n$.

The matrix representation goes like: put the coordinates (wrt. basis $B$) of the image of the $k$th basis element into the $k$th column. E.g. the 4th basis element is $x^4$ (counting from $0$), its image (under the given map, now differentiation) is $4x^3$, so it uses only the third basis vector of $B$, with coefficient $4$. So, the matrix is
$$\pmatrix{0&1&0&\dots&0\\0&0&2&\dots&0\\ 0&0&0&\ddots& \vdots\\
&\vdots&&\ddots &n \\0&0&0&\dots&0}\,.$$
You should calculate then its square and observe that it belongs to the second derivative operator.